# Time complexity of T(n) = 1600T(n/4) + n!

Tags: time-complexity, factorial

I'm trying to find the time complexity of T(n) = 1600T(n/4) + n! . So far I have thought of changing n! to something usable by the master theorem. Stirling's approximation gives us the equation

$$\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n$$

I am confused on whether the value for d in the master theorem would become n or if I am looking at this the wrong way. Any advice on how to find the time complexity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the right case of the master theorem, in the relation
$$T(n) = aT\left(\frac{n}b\right)+f(n)$$
you have to compare $n^{\log_b a}$ and $f(n)$:

1. if $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^c)$ with $c<\log_b a$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$;
2. if $f(n) = \Omega(n^c)$ with $c > \log_b a$, then $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$;
3. if $f(n) = \Theta(n^c)$ with $c=\log_b a$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^c \log n)$.

In this case, you have to compare $n^{\log_b a}$ with $\log_b a = \log_4(1600) \simeq 5.32$ with $n!$. You can use Stirling approximation to compare those two functions.

Comment: How do you compare the two functions using Stirling approximation?